# iis bindings on shared server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have a scenario where I have many domains (could be hundreds) pointing to my one web application for example

site1.com
site2.com
site3.com
.... etc

All point to my single web app, this app will be in a shared hosting environment.

The only way I can think of configuring these bindings in IIS is to send my shared hosting company an email every time I need a new binding. Is there a better way? for example  some how sending all host headers to my site? How do I do that?

Comment: Doesn't your host have a control panel? A decent hosting provider should provide you a control panel where you can add these bindings yourself

Answer (score -1):

You probably need your own IP address to do this. Then you could just not specify a `Host name` in your binding:

[image: IIS Binding]

You will need to specify your IP in the binding though.

This means that as long as your DNS points all sites to your IP, then your site should respond.

Comment: You don't need your own IP to do this. What's more, the OP mentioned he's on a shared host, so the host will probably not allow his site to be the default.

Comment: @Kenneth - how do you know that the hosting company will not allow him to have his own IP?